# Using RxJava 2 to modify the UI gives the exception: Animators may only be run on Looper thread

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm currently trying to move an application over to RxJava 2 to replace our broadcast receiver methods of passing events around. The goal here was to used Rx with a pubSub pattern in mind.

(Just a heads up, the following class which acts as an event bus was taken from an article I found online and I do believe I don't understand the working to 100% which I is probably why I can't find the fix of the problem).

**My problem:** I have a library that gives emits certain events (in this case a Bluetooth library that handles connection, pairing, data processing, etc...). The activities interested in these events can subscribe to certain or all of them to get notified when the library has something. I guess it is important to say that I AM getting responses from my library (so data), but I cannot change the UI (I can add words to a textview but that's about it) when my activity receives the response. I do understand that the threads that onNext() will run on is where the subscribe was called for, and as of right now, the subscribe on is NOT explicitly called by my activity ( I'll paste in the code below).

Snippet of activity registration to events:

```
  EventBus.subscribe(EventBus.Events.CONNECTED, this,  new Consumer<Object>()
                          {
                              @Override
                              public void accept(Object device)
                              {
                                  if(device instanceof DeviceStructure)
                                  {
                                    if(uuid.equals(((DeviceStructure) device).getUUID()))
                                    {
                                        status_value.append("device connected " + ((DeviceStructure) device).getUUID());
                                    }
                                    else if(name.equals(((DeviceStructure) device).getName()))
                                    {
                                        status_value.append( "device connected " + name + " " + address);
                                    }
                                  }

                              }
                          }
    );


    EventBus.subscribe(EventBus.Events.PAIRED, this, new Consumer<Object>()
    {
        @Override
        public void accept(Object device)
        {
            if(device instanceof DeviceStructure)
            {
                if(((DeviceStructure) device).getPairedStatus())
                {
                            uuid = ((DeviceStructure) device).getUUID();
                            status_value.append("device paired " + uuid);
                            pair.setEnabled(false);
                            sync.setEnabled(true);
                            unpair.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I am able to modified the status_value values and display some text. However, I am unable to do pair.setEnabled(false) ( The part where the error gets thrown)

The event bus class:

```
   public final class EventBus {


public enum Events
{
    CONNECTED,
    PAIRED
}

private static Map<Events, PublishSubject<Object>>      sSubjectMap       = new HashMap<>();
private static Map<Object, CompositeDisposable> sSubscriptionsMap = new HashMap<>();


private EventBus() {
    // hidden constructor
}

/**
 * Get the subject or create it if it's not already in memory.
 */
@NonNull
private static PublishSubject<Object> getSubject(Events event) {
    PublishSubject<Object> subject = sSubjectMap.get(event);
    if (subject == null) {
        subject = PublishSubject.create();
        subject.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        sSubjectMap.put(event, subject);
    }

    return subject;
}

/**
 * Get the CompositeDisposable or create it if it's not already in memory.
 */
@NonNull
private static CompositeDisposable getCompositeDisposable(@NonNull Object subscriber) {
    CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = sSubscriptionsMap.get(subscriber);
    if (compositeDisposable == null) {
        compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        sSubscriptionsMap.put(subscriber, compositeDisposable);
    }

    return compositeDisposable;
}

/**
 * Subscribe to the specified subject and listen for updates on that subject. Pass in an object to associate
 * your registration with, so that you can unsubscribe later.
 * <br/><br/>
 */
public static void subscribe(Events subject, @NonNull Object subscriber, @NonNull Consumer<Object> action) {
    Disposable disposable = getSubject(subject).subscribe(action);
    getCompositeDisposable(subscriber).add(disposable);
}

/**
 * Unregisters this object from the bus, removing all subscriptions.
 * This should be called when the object is going to go out of memory.
 */
public static void unregister(@NonNull Object lifecycle) {
    //We have to remove the composition from the map, because once you dispose it can't be used anymore
    CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = sSubscriptionsMap.remove(lifecycle);
    if (compositeDisposable != null) {
        compositeDisposable.dispose();
    }
}

/**
 * Publish an object to the specified subject for all subscribers of that subject.
 */
public static void publish(Events subject, @NonNull Object message) {
    getSubject(subject).onNext(message);
}
}
```

I have tried the following solutions proposed online to indicate that I would like the subscriber to run on the main thread ( which should be the UI thread, unless I got that wrong).

```
        subject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        subject.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        subject.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        subject.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(Looper.getMainLooper()));
```

I have also found this link : https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/371 but the solution provided still doesn't seem to like what my activity is doing.

I guess it is also worth noting that when I enter the accept method in PAIRED action, the thread isn't the UI thread at that point.

Edit:

I'll leave this on just for other people like me. I had to add the observeOn to my disposable object and not in my getSubject() method which is where I added it from.

Comment: I don't see Animator in the code?

Comment: I mean, that is the error. I can try to go get the logs to paste it on here. It happens on   pair.setEnabled(false) which is a Button.

Comment: can you update your thread to give an idea on what you are trying to do with old code especially so that your post makes sense? I find hard to connect what you are actually trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
if (subject == null) {
    subject = PublishSubject.create();
    subject.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

The result of `subscribeOn` is ignored.

Technically what you must do is somehow interject an `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` before you receive your event from the relay to the subscriber.

A possibility is to define an `Observable.Transformer` that you can `compose` which will apply the `observeOn`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> observeOnMain() {
    return tObservable -> tObservable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

and

```
.compose(observeOnMain())
.subscribe(subscriber);
```